# Replacing comma for numerics in csv file

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that looks like so:

The file is comma-separated...however, the comma is also used for commas in digits. the good thing is that i only need to remove a comma that sits between 2 numbers:

```
a,b,100,000.00,2018-01-01,c
c,d,20,000.0,2017-12-01,e
e,f,1,000,000.00,2015-11-10,g
```

and convert this to:

```
a,b,100000.00,2018-01-01,c
c,d,20000.0,2017-12-01,e
e,f,1000000.00,2015-11-10,g
```

i was thinking of using `(?<=\d),(?=\d+\.\d+)` but this only takes care of the comma at the (1000) place but not the (1000000) place. Is there a way to do this recursively? Alternatively I can call this subsitution twice.

Comment: why not just remove any digit comma notations altogether?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Is data in column 2 only text?

Comment: yes @MarkTolonen

Comment: You only need to make fractional part optional: `(?<=\d),(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,|$))`. Also it would be better to do `(?<=,|^)(\d+),(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,|$))` and replace with   `\1`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/6xfhrB/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s="""a,b,100,000.00,2018-01-01,c
c,d,20,000.0,2017-12-01,e
e,f,1,000,000.00,2015-11-10,g"""
print( re.sub(r"(?<![^,])\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?![^,])", lambda x: x.group().replace(',',''), s) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/b9iJ3y). Output:

```
a,b,100000.00,2018-01-01,c
c,d,20000.0,2017-12-01,e
e,f,1000000.00,2015-11-10,g
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?<![^,])` - a comma must appear immediately to the left or start of string
- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `,` - comma
  - `\d{3}` - three digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?![^,])` - a comma must appear immediately to the right or end of string

All commas are removed from the found match using `lambda x: x.group().replace(',','')`.

Comment: sorry i updated the question, adding the date component

Comment: Yeah, see https://regex101.com/r/WmmyNc/1/, this a PCRE equivalent demo. It accounts for the `,` or start/end of string on both ends of the match.

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookbehind and lookahead `regex`:

```
import re

s = 'a,b,100,000.00,c'
print(re.sub(r'(?<=\d),(?=\d)', '', s))
# a,b,100000.00,c
```